# materialTabControl not displayed when the form starts

Tags: c#, winforms, material-design

I hooked up a style MaterialSkin in my WinForm. I added materialTabControl to my form. When I run the program, the names of the tabs disappear. I checked all the properties and everything is fine with them. What could be the problem? The remaining elements are displayed normally, except for materialTabControl

```
using MaterialSkin;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;


public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Report that to the creator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add MaterialTabSelector first.

Here are steps to configure the MaterialTabControl:

1. Add a MaterialTabSelector to the form.

[image: this]

2. Add a MaterialTabControl to the form.

[image: this]

3. Click on the MaterialTabSelector in the design view, go to the properties and update the BaseTabControl property to point to the MaterialTabControl added in step 2.

[image: this]

Now you can Ctrl + F5 and see the result. Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Nice tutorial my friend.

Comment: @кириллбалашов: You're always welcome, my friend :d

Comment: @Tomato32 Since you're here, I have 1 more question. Is it possible to make a semblance of a CheckBoxList in Material Design? There is no such element in the set.

Comment: @кириллбалашов: Yeah, you're right. It doesn't have CheckBoxList control. You can just use MaterialCheckbox this time. Maybe need to code more, my friend :))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MaterialListView with Checkboxes enabled in List mode... although a MaterialCheckListbox may be available by now.